# Using of sizeof operator on itself in static member array definition

Tags: c++, c++98

Why am I getting this:

```
error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'A'
```

when I try to do this:

```
class A
{
  int m_i;
  static char m_j[sizeof(A)];
};
```

I was under the assumption that it is obviously clear that sizeof(A) will be sizeof(int) in this case. But my compiler doesn't seem to think so.

Comment: You can get around it by declaring m_j as char* and allocating the space in the external declaration.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc you misread the question : `m_j` is static, and making it the same size as the class makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 5):

As the error message suggests, `sizeof` can only operate on complete types. At the point you invoke it, `A` is not complete.

Comment: That sounds reasonable...
Is there any workaround to achieve what I tied to do?

Comment: @user2950911 If A's private members are only used in one source file, you could declare the `m_j` array as a static global object inside that source file.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ compiler analyzes your code from top to bottom. Your class is not completely defined at the point you invoke `sizeof`, therefore, the size is not yet determinable. For instance, what if another member declaration was below that line:

```
class A
{
  int m_i;
  static char m_j[sizeof(A)]; // Uh oh, m_i2 is not known here, yet
  int m_i2;
};
```

Due to problems like this, you can use `sizeof` only after the class is completely defined, i.e., after its closing curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you use a template :

```
template <class = void>
struct A {
    int i;

    static auto& m_j() {
        static char arr[sizeof(A)];
        return arr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto array = A<>::m_j();
}
```

The compiler waits until the use of `m_j` to instantiate the function, at which point `A` has been fully declared.

Live example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da9bfe4b21e5d13f)

Comment: Why do you need a template? The reason it works is because you put the static array inside a member function.

Comment: @juanchopanza You need the delayed instantiation if you don't use the deduced return type. I'm not sure if it's actually standard behaviour.